# Passing parameter between action blocks in LoadRunner

Tags: parameters, loadrunner

Having 8 separate action blocks in my vugen script, one for each web_custom_request() containing a webservice test (I am using web html/http) protocol, I want to capture an ID to be used in the subsequent web service requests in each of the 8 action blocks. I will use web_reg_save_param() before the web service call thorugh the web custom request and refer this in the other action blocks. Is it possible? As in can I refer saved parameters across multiple actions within the same VUGen script?

Answer (score 1):

Any LoadRunner variable created with web_reg_save_param() is global.  So, yes, you may collect in action1 asnd use in action2 through action*n*